# High computational time in using backslash for soving sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I built a sparse matrix `A` at each step as follows:

```
% 1 < DX < 120000 

A = sparse(i,j,s,DX,DX,6*DX)

b = (1, DX)
```

The problem that I am dealing with is a discretization problem. I have maximum 120000 nodes. Each of these nodes have special characters and I choose only the ones that meet a (previously) defined criteria. The number of these chosen ones is `DX` and is completely dependent on the physical process.

I am using backslash in `x = A\b`. But as the size of A could become quite big, the computational time rises drastically (more than `10e5` time steps have `DX > 6e4`). As far as I know, backslash operation is already well optimized in MATLAB but I would like to know:

1. Would it make sense to use `codegen` and convert the code to C?
2. Does any one know an alternative method instead of backslash, so that the computational time decreases (maybe an iterative method?)?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! The obvious question is "implement what?" -- could you add some more details about the problem you are trying solve (PDE (presumably), specific discretization,...); in particular, what is `DX`? It is very unusual that the size of the matrix changes between time steps, so maybe your modelling is simply wrong.

Comment: The answer to your first question is an emphatic *No*; the heavy lifting behind backslash is not implemented in Matlab but in one of the (FORTRAN-based and hand-optimized) numerical linear algebra libraries bundled with Matlab.

Comment: Thank you Christian for the answer. The problem that I am dealing is a sort of discretization problem. I have maximum 120000 nodes and each of these nodes are having special charachters and I choose only the ones that meet my criteria. the number of these chosen ones is DX and is completely dependent on the physical process. By saying implement a better idea, I meant clearly an alternative method instead of backslash, so that the compuattional time decreases  (maybe an iterative method)

Comment: I don't understand your sparse() function call; it doesn't look like valid MATLAB code to me. Exactly how are you constructing your sparse matrix, A?

Comment: It would really be helpful if you added a description of your discretization problem; otherwise it is very difficult to recommend alternative approaches. (For example, the performance of iterative solvers depends very much on the structure of your matrix.) You should also make sure (by profiling) that the bottleneck is indeed the solver and not something else; e.g., preallocating a sparse matrix and then inserting entries is notoriously wasteful because after every insertion, the whole data structure has to be rewritten.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I corrected the text. Actually I use A = sparse(i,j,s,DX,DX,6*DX) in order to create A. in which i,j and s are obtained according to the physical process and the criteria defined.

Comment: @ChristianClason: Actually I am aware of the fact that iterative methods are highly dependent on the structure of the matrix, I did try to find if my matrix is having a special structure, but it couldn't! So I would say the data are quite randomly distributed in the matrix. Besides I have done profiling and I am sure that the code is slow because of backslash. what you mentioned about pre-allocation is not affecting the backslash operation, it just leads to not to spend time on allocating values to matrix A members.

Comment: @John13 Then there's not much that one could say except "try gmres or bicgstab, see if it works (better)". An actually useful answer would be "here's how you can avoid such nasty matrices", but this is impossible without more details about your problem.

Comment: Correction -- you might try reordering the matrix before calling backslash (look at `colamd` and `symrcm`), although to my knowledge current versions of the sparse direct solvers in Matlab already implement some sort of reordering.

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether the matrix changes at each step or remains the same.  If there's one matrix that remains unchanged then it would be vastly more efficient to compute the sparse Cholesky factorization once at the start of the loop and use the Cholesky factors in each iteration to solve the linear system.

Comment: I agree with the general consensus that more details need to be added. Mentioning "a discretization problem" is too vague to give advice about linear solvers.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: during some time steps (e.g. 5 time steps) only 3 matrix members change. and then after these steps, value of all the matrix members change completely. Do you think still there is an efficient way for those periods that matrix "almost" stays unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using one of the iterative solvers that MATLAB provides, as x = A\b works well for many systems, you can run into memory issues causing slowdowns.

Alternately, MATLAB has a number of built in functions for iteratively solving Ax=b for sparse matrices, such as `pcq(), bigcg(), cgs()`, etc.

See the [MATLAB Documentation on interative methods for solving systems of linear equations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/linear-equations-iterative-methods.html?searchHighlight=iterative%20methods%20linear%20equations)

Answer (score 0):

Since (I assume) your matrix size and possibly its structure changes from time step to time step you can't, for example, compute an efficient ordering once and then reuse that with e.g. the chol() function to compute a solution.

The backslash operator does incur some slight overhead determining if your matrix is dense/sparse, symmetric, etc. If, for example, your matrix is symmetric, you might improve performance slightly by computing an ordering (e.g. symamd()) and then using that with chol().

If I understand right, you are computing for 1e6 time steps? I don't suppose there is an alternate time integration algorithm you can use that would require fewer time steps?

Comment: Thank you Bill for the answer. you are right, the structure does not changed and I will try to implement the method you explained. Regarding the time steps, I have 2e6 time steps, more or less, in 1e6 of them DX is too big. The time steps is not something that I can modify. They are dependent on the process and the process is already proved!